# onload event on iframe working differently in ie and firefox/googlechrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, iframe

here is my aspx page for iframe

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="dynamicForm" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>                    
                <iframe id="iTargetLoader" name="iTargetLoader" width="200" height="50" onload="onLoadFn()"></iframe> 
            </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

here is my onloadfn function in javascript for the onload event of iframe

```
function onLoadFn() {
        //debugger;        
        document.getElementById("iTargetLoader").contentWindow.document.defaultView.frameElement.innerText;
        var frame = document.getElementById("iTargetLoader");
        var contentDoc = (frame.contentWindow || frame.contentDocument);        
        if (contentDoc != null && contentDoc.document.body != null) {            
            var serverResult = contentDoc.document.body.innerText;            
            var regSuccess = /success/i;
            if (regSuccess.test(serverResult)) {                
                if (parseInt($('#ContentPlaceHolder1_hdn_qstnadd').val()) == 1) {                    
                        addQuestion();                                   
                    $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_hdn_qstnadd').val(0);
                }                                  
                //alert('success!');
                //return "success!";
            }
            else {
                if ($.trim(serverResult) == "") {
                    //alert("empty!");
                }
                else {
                    alert("failed!" + serverResult + "Please Contact Your Administrator!");
                    window.parent.window.open("", "_self");
                    window.parent.window.close();
                }
                //return "failure!";
            }
        }
        else {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Here a feedback from a servlet is loaded to the iframe ie "iTargetLoader" i am trying to check the content of the iframe after it is loaded whether it is success or not.It is working fine in IE but when I use firefox or google chrome in the onload event the loading of the iframe does not complete and hence the inner html is shown null. But in IE the loading completes first and the innerhtml shows the feedback. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

So your question is more to make it cross-browser compatible:
Let's get the quirks out then ...

**HTML or ASPX**

Use a reference `this` so you don't need to get that object more than once.

```
<iframe id="iTargetLoader" name="iTargetLoader" width="200" height="50" onload="javascript: onLoadFn(this);"></iframe>
```

**JS**

```
// a global function needs to be defined first before it can be used
// most likely not an issue in this example but
// similar to addQuestion you might want to change it to IIFE
// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression
function onLoadFn(frame) {
    // define your variables
    var contentDoc,
        serverResult,
        regSuccess = /success/i,
        qstnadd;

    // test your parameter exists, in this case the iframe (this)
    if (frame) {
        // Note: Because of security reasons, the contents of a document can be accessed from another document only if the two documents are located in the same domain.
        // Note: Internet Explorer 8 (and higher) supports the contentDocument property only if a !DOCTYPE is specified. For earlier versions of IE, use the contentWindow property.
        contentDoc = frame.contentWindow || frame.contentDocument;

        if (contentDoc) {
            // testing the proper document object here
            if (contentDoc.document){
                contentDoc = contentDoc.document;
            }

            serverResult = contentDoc.body.innerText || "";

            if (regSuccess.test(serverResult)) {
                // request your object once
                // .Net supports something like IDMode static which can help to determine the ID here.
                qstnadd = $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_hdn_qstnadd');
                // use a raddix when using parseInt
                if (parseInt(qstnadd.val(), 10) === 1) {
                    addQuestion();
                    qstnadd.val(0);
                }
            } else {
                // looks trivial to me
                if ($.trim(serverResult) === "") {
                    alert("empty");
                } else {
                    alert("failed!" + serverResult + "Please Contact Your Administrator!");
                    window.parent.window.open("", "_self");
                    window.parent.window.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Even if this doesn't solve your problem directly, I'm sure you can pinpoint the problem better this way. Wild guess, your problem is in the `contentDoc.document` since you're requesting a `window.document.body` or a `document.body` but not a `window.document.document.body` although the latter might work in IE ^^

Comment: thanks for the explanation but the problem is the contentDoc.document is empty ie the servlet feedback is not loaded in the iframe ie contentDoc at this moment in browser except IE.

Comment: so you're saying that `frame.contentWindow` AND `frame.contentDocument` are both empty? If that's the case there's another problem outside this code.

Comment: yes there is problem in load event. IE and google chrome seems to act differently for the load event. as I said earlier IE loads the iframe before document is ready but google chrome loads the iframe at last. how can I make google chrome act like IE for the load event?